# I have created an audio file from mobile but it doesn't play using HTML5 <audio> and even on browser

Tags: typescript, mobile, nativescript, html5-audio

I have a mobile app which records an audio then after recording, the audio file is sent to a web server. The problem is the audio file doesn't play using HTML5  and even on browser but if I play the audio file on mobile or to any media player, it works. I have tried .wav, .ogg, and .mp3 file extension but none of them worked on HTML5  or directly on browser.

It shows this image [image]

I'm using Nativescript on my mobile app. And i'm using nativescript-audio plugin for recording an audio and nativescript-background-http for sending the audio file to web server.

Here's my code on sending the audio file to web server

```
var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");

var request = {
    url: UploadURL,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "File-Name": "Abi_2018-11-07T05:40:21+08:00.ogg",
        "User-Id": id
    },
    description: "{ 'uploading': '" + "recording.ogg" + "' }"
};
var task = session.uploadFile(fs.path.normalize(recordedFile.path), request);
```

I even tried specifying the `Content-type` to all possible audio mime type but neither of them worked.

Comment: What MIME type are you serving as?

Comment: If you aren't specifying an encoder and file format when setting up the recorder, the device may be using a default format like 3GPP that isn't supported in HTML5. The available encoders and file formats will be OS specific and I highly doubt iOS will let you record to ogg/vorbis. As @SLaks points out, you'll also need to serve the file with a Content-Type header that matches its file format, the extension alone might not do it.

Comment: I've tried already using `audio/ogg` and `audio/*` but neither of 'em worked.

Comment: Have tested with any other ogg file on your browser? e,g. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Example_of_flats_in_music.ogg

Comment: @NarendraMongiya Yes, and it worked. Just these audio files that's from the mobile app.